# Upper bound for product of exponents of prime factorization

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization

Let $p(n)$ be the product of the exponents of the prime factorization of $n$. For example,
$$p(5184)=p(2^{6}\cdot 3^{4})=24,\qquad
p(65536)=p(2^{16})=16.$$
Is $p(n) = O(\log^{k}(n))$ for some constant $k$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the answer is no: consider the product $n$ of all squares of primes $\leq x$. Then $p(x)$ is roughly $2^{x/\log(x)}$ and $n$ is roughly $\exp(2x)$ by the prime number theorem.

Comment: @SteffenKionke: You are right. See my answer which provides more detail (we typed our answers simultaneously).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, $p(n)$ is not bounded by a power of $\log(n)$. For example, if $$n=p_1^2\dots p_r^2,$$ 
where $p_1<p_2<\dots$ is the sequence of prime numbers, then by the Prime Number Theorem we have
$$ \log n=2(\log p_1+\dots +\log p_r)=(2+o(1))p_r=(2+o(1))r\log r, $$
so that $r=(1/2+o(1))\log n/\log\log n$, and therefore
$$ p(n)=2^r = \exp\left(\frac{(\log2+o(1))(\log n)}{2\log\log n}\right).$$
Note that the exponent on the right hand side grows faster than any constant times $\log\log n$.

In fact the right hand side is a general upper bound for $p(n)$. To see this, consider a general $n$ with prime power decomposition 
$$n=q_1^{k_1}\dots q_r^{k_r},$$ 
where each $q_j$ is a prime and each $k_j$ is a positive integer. Let $m>0$ be a parameter, then
$$ p(n)=\prod_{1\leq j\leq r} k_j\leq 
\prod_{\substack{1\leq j\leq r\\q_j\leq m}}k_j
\prod_{\substack{1\leq j\leq r\\q_j>m}}2^{k_j/2}\leq 
\left(\frac{\log n}{\log 2}\right)^m 
\left(\prod_{\substack{1\leq j\leq r\\q_j>m}} q_j^{k_j/2}\right)^{\frac{\log 2}{\log m}},$$
whence
$$ p(n)\leq(\log n)^m n^\frac{\log 2}{2\log m}=\exp\left(m\log\log n+\frac{(\log 2)(\log n)}{2\log m}\right).$$
Choosing $m:=\log n/(\log\log n)^3$ yields that
$$ p(n)\leq \exp\left(\frac{(\log2+o(1))(\log n)}{2\log\log n}\right). $$
This argument was inspired by Section I.5.2 of Tenenbaum: Introduction to analytic and probabilistic number theory (Cambridge University Press, 1995).